# set extension in OpenRTB Protobuf Java

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

How do I set the response extension for OpenRTB

OpenRTB.proto @ https://github.com/google/openrtb/blob/master/openrtb-core/src/main/protobuf/openrtb.proto

extension.proto @ https://developers.google.com/ad-exchange/rtb/downloads/openrtb-adx-proto.txt

```
AdxExt.BidExt.Builder bidExtBuilder = AdxExt.BidExt.newBuilder()
                            .addImpressionTrackingUrl(url);

BidResponse.SeatBid.Bid.Builder seatBidBuilder = BidResponse.SeatBid.Bid.newBuilder()
                    .setId(id)
                    .setImpid(impId)
                    .setPrice(price)
                    .setExtension(AdxExt.bid, bidExtBuilder); // issue here, compile time error


// setExtension signature 
public final <Type> BuilderType setExtension(final Extension<MessageType, Type> extension, final Type value)
```

what setExtension or addExtension methods wants to get ? is it has something related to

```
extend com.google.openrtb.BidResponse.SeatBid.Bid {
    // Extension key for AdX Bid.ext.
    optional BidExt bid = 1014;
}
```

how do I add an extension of BidExt which I added an impression_tracking_url to it into seatBidBuilder ?

reference https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java-generated#extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setExtension(AdxExt.bid, bidExtBuilder.**build()**);